# Undefined reference to log4cxx when adding openni_camera dependency to package

Tags: ros, kinect, log4cxx, ros-fuerte, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been struggling with this for a few hours. I created a package depending on
`openni`, `openni_camera` and `openni_launch`.

My problem is: on compilation, i'm getting

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/listener
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*)'
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Level::getError()'
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Level::getWarn()'
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase'
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase::~ObjectPtrBase()'
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so: error: undefined reference to 'log4cxx::Level::getFatal()'
```

I thought it was whining about the fact that I didn't link the log4cxx library on compilation. So I added this in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} /usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```

but it didn't change much. Then I tried the answer from another question (which I'm not allowed to mention giving my baby karma) suggesting to use `target_link_libraries()` but I couldn't use it successfully.

Any ideas? NB: I'm running fuerte on ubuntu 12.04. Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60582/undefined-reference-to-log4cxx-when-adding-openni_camera-dependency-to-package/) by [tkrugg](https://answers.ros.org/users/4669/tkrugg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I don't know if this is still useful, but I just solved a similar problem. In any case, I'll leave my solution here.

What I did was to add the following line to the begginning of my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
link_libraries(-llog4cxx)
```

What this does is link every executable to the `log4cxx` library.

Keep in mind that `link_libraries()` is deprecated, so if this problem only occurs with one executable, it is preferred to use `target_link_libraries()`. I did not use this because the errors occurred in every executable, so `link_libraries()` was an easier solution.

If this does not solve your problem, don't hesitate in asking me for help, I'll try my best to help you solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Throst Gunnulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/5427/throst-gunnulf/) with karma: 56 on 2013-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0